# Do you have to be responsive to comments on your question to get good answers?

Tags: discussion, comments, best-practices

Do you have to keep looking at the site to look at the comments and respond to them?

Comment: Why would you not check back on the site from time to time? If you asked a question, presumably you wanted an answer

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> Do you have to be responsive to comments on your question to get good answers?

In a comment someone may ask for clarifications on your question, in which case yes, only by clarifying what you want to know you can expect someone to address that in an answer. At the same time, people in comments often point out reasons why the questions might be closed (e.g. it may go against community guidelines on homework, level of effort, or how many questions you are asking in a single question), so addressing those will guarantee your question stays open. Also, people often comment on the style of the question, specifically whether the maths is in Latex or not, which improves readability and hence chance of someone answering.

> Do you have to keep looking at the site to look at the comments and
> respond to them?

I don't fully understand this question. 
You don't *have* to do anything, if you don't want to. 
This website is free, so people dedicate their time to answer questions. I guess it is a courtesy on your side to follow up on answers to your questions by upvoting them, accepting them, or leaving comments asking for clarifications on the answer -- but it's all optional. For comments left on your question, it is in *your* interest to address them, for that would increase the chance of having someone answer your question.